# ASP.net Web API Always returning all results not a single as needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Hi so i have been trying every method on the net to get this right i have added a mdf database as well as created a model of tables in that database so, when I enter the standard list all users feature it works perfectly but I Added a function as per code bellow that according to multiple sources on the net is supposed to bring back a single user according to the content of that table in other words /api/users will return all, but /api/users/123 will return all as well, and that should not be the case according to me it should only return user 123

please let me know what i am doing wrong any help will be greatly appreciated

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Web.Http;
 using System.Web.Http.Description;
 using APPAPI.Models;


 namespace APPAPI.Controllers
 {
 public class UsersController : ApiController
 {
    private APPDATAENT _context;
    public UsersController()
    {
        _context = new APPDATAENT();
    }
    //get api/users
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _context.Users.ToList();
    }
    public User GetMember(string member)
    {
        var membership = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == 
 member);
        if (membership == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        return membership;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried stating int where string member is i do get errors although the Username table is only numbers i think the UserName Column is set to Char not int etc.

Comment: oh you call `GetMember` method in wrong way. your url is `/api/users/123` actually hit `GetUsers` method not `GetMember`. for getting only single user you have to set `Route` for `GetMember` also like `[HttpGet("api/users/{id}")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default route template for convention-based routes is usually

```
"api/{controller}/{id}"
```

Note the `id` parameter name.

Your action is defined as

```
public User GetMember(string member);
```

that `member` is the problem. It does not match the route template for that action so it defaults back to the `GetUsers()` action as the `id` parameter is usually optional by default in the template.

refactor action

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetMember(string id) {
    var membership = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserName == id);
    if (membership == null)
        return  NotFound();
    return Ok(membership);
}
```

Comment: @Lee Glad to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can i ask another question, how would i parse just the id like just get certain results for the request, i am very new to API work i have researched so much yet no tutorial shows how to get only one column for the data requested :)

Comment: @Lee you extract the desired data from the returned object and construct the desired response. In your example you returned the entire object, but you could have just as easily created return only the desired values.

Comment: Got it thanx again

Comment: nice one @Nkosi